# "Access to posting shares denied" error when posting public messages using the linkedin api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

I am trying send out messages using the [linkedin ruby api](https://github.com/pengwynn/linkedin) to the API end point : `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares`, but everytime I get this error : `LinkedIn::Errors::AccessDeniedError ((403): Access to posting shares denied)`. What is wrong?

code:

```
#fetch client object
client = LinkedIn::Client.new('er0xev11ktyj', 'qw7hfgR4wT8Hztpl')

#auth
request_token = client.request_token(:oauth_callback => callback_url)
session[:linkedin_token] = request_token.token
session[:linkedin_secret] = request_token.secret
redirect_to request_token.authorize_url

#inside callback url
atoken,asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:linkedin_token], session[:linkedin_secret], params[:oauth_verifier])

#api call for posting message
client.authorize_from_access(atoken, asecret)
client.add_share({:comment => "Hey!"}) #throws error!
```

Do I need to specify scope parameters? If yes, how do I implement this in my code?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to connect? If LinkedIn is returning proper status codes, this sounds like the account you're using to access the API does not have permission to do what you want to.

Comment: dude you posted your app's secret

Comment: The scope values should involve more permissions:  like https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 said: e.g. scope=r_fullprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_share

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the default consumer options and append scope to the `request_token_path`

```
 consumer_options = {
    :request_token_path => "/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+w_share",
    :access_token_path  => "/uas/oauth/accessToken",
    :authorize_path     => "/uas/oauth/authorize",
    :api_host           => "https://api.linkedin.com",
    :auth_host          => "https://www.linkedin.com"
  }
 LinkedIn::Client.new(ckey, csecret, consumer_options)
```